# asyncio.gather throws RuntimeError: Task got bad yield

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I want to run a few tasks "in parallel" using [asyncio.gather()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather):

```py
import asyncio

async def foo():
    return 42

async def main():
    results = await asyncio.gather(foo() for i in range(10))
    print(results)

asyncio.run(main())
```

But it fails with `RuntimeError: Task got bad yield`:

```
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/asyncio/events.py:88: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'foo' was never awaited
  self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/asyncio/runners.py", line 43, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 583, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in main
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <genexpr>
RuntimeError: Task got bad yield: <coroutine object foo at 0x10555bd40>
```

Answer (score 24):

The function `asyncio.gather()` accepts each task as separate argument. Like this:

```
await asyncio.gather(task1, task2, task3)
```

So the solution is to replace

```py
    results = await asyncio.gather(foo() for i in range(10))
```

with

```py
    results = await asyncio.gather(*[foo() for i in range(10)])
```

Comment: Did you actually answer your question?

Comment: Yes. https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: @ThomasSchillaci that's allowed. If a future reader stumbles on the question then it would have an answer for them to see.

Comment: `await asyncio.gather(*(foo() for i in range(10)))` is another option, with the advantage that it avoids creation of an (immediately discarded) temporary list.